# Partitions of unity in constructive mathematics

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, constructive-mathematics

Can someone point me to any substitutes for the partition of unity in Bishop's constructive mathematics?

In particular, under what circumstances can we construct a partition of unity subordinate to some open cover of a compact set in Euclidean space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my PhD thesis [modern intuitionistic topology](https://www.fwaaldijk.nl/modern%20intuitionistic%20topology.pdf) in chapter 3 there is a comprehensive treatment of partitions of unity within BISH.

In essence the main theorem is that per-enumerable open covers of a metric space admit a subordinate partition of unity. An open cover is per-enumerable iff it is an enumerable collection of open sets which themselves are an enumerable union of basic open metric balls (where the base point comes from a fixed enumerable dense set.)

Comment: sorry the link was defective... but should work now.

Comment: Can your result be related to complete regularity (every open set is the inverse image of $(0, 1)$)?